# How does Thor get this in Endgame?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In the final fight with Thanos in *Avengers: Endgame*, we see that Thor uses **Stormbreaker** and **Mjölnir** which Captain America uses later in the fighting. But I didn't see how he gets his hammer.

So, how does Thor gets his hammer (Mjölnir) back? Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I have missed the part where this scene happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the end of the scene when Thor is talking to his mother he summons Mjölnir as a test of his worth.

He then carries it alongside Stormbreaker for the rest of the film.

Comment: Thanks, Maybe I really missed it. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: And then Captain America takes it with him at the end of the film to return it to its correct time.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Yes you missed it.

He got it in his time travel trip. There was a specific scene for it

He got it while talking to his mother and he tested his worthiness by sticking his hand out to get Mjölnir. It came to him and he even noted to himself that he is still worthy